# SQL error- No matching or unique primary key for this column list

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys, ddl

Hello I'm new to learning SQL as well as new to the site! I've been trying to mend these tables together with a foreign key on the Job attribute and I keep running into this error "SQL error- No matching or unique primary key for this column-list."

From what I do understand and have been able to figure through trial and error is that the problem is specifically with my foreign key constraint, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix it.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
Create Table Names
(
FirstName VARCHAR2(25),
LastName VARCHAR2(25),
Address VARCHAR2(25),
Job VARCHAR2(25),

Constraint Name_PK
Primary Key (FirstName, LastName)
);

Create Table Jobs
(
Job VARCHAR2(25),
Salary VARCHAR2(5),
Assistant VARCHAR2(5),

Constraint Jobs_PK
Primary Key (Job),

Constraint Jobs_FK
Foreign Key (Job)
References Names(Job)
);
```

Comment: Flip the constraint  make Names dependent on Jobs.

Comment: Hopefully there's no 2nd employee named *John Smith*.

Comment: Not sure that trial and error + SO is the best way to learn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few things you need to improve with your design.

> A FOREIGN KEY in one table points to a PRIMARY KEY in another table.
>
> http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Column `Job` is obviously not a primary key in table `Names`. This is the reason for error *"SQL error- No matching or unique primary key for this column-list."*

It looks like instead you intend to reference `Jobs` from `Names` table. Meaning that there is foreign key constraint in `Names` table referencing `Jobs` with `Job` column. You can have multiple Names that share same Job.

You will need to slightly change foreign key and move it to your definition of `Names` table:

```
Create Table Jobs
(
Job VARCHAR2(25),
Salary VARCHAR2(5),
Assistant VARCHAR2(5),

Constraint Jobs_PK
Primary Key (Job)
);

Create Table Names
(
FirstName VARCHAR2(25),
LastName VARCHAR2(25),
Address VARCHAR2(25),
Job VARCHAR2(25),

Constraint Name_PK
Primary Key (FirstName, LastName),

        Constraint Jobs_FK
        Foreign Key (Job)
        References Jobs(Job)
);
```

---

If you really-really need to reference `Names` from `Jobs`, all you need to do is to list `FirstName` and `LastName` in your existing code like below:

References Names(**FirstName**, **LastName**)

---

As a side note, it is usually not a great idea to have two column primary key, but if you have one like that you will have to reference as two column primary key.

Answer (score 1):

You have the foreign keys in the wrong order.  You want:

```
Create Table Names (
    FirstName VARCHAR2(25),
    LastName VARCHAR2(25),
    Address VARCHAR2(25),
    Job VARCHAR2(25),
    Constraint pk_Names Primary Key (FirstName, LastName)
    Constraint fk_Names_Job Foreign Key (Job) References Jobs(Job)
);
```

And then `Names` needs to be defined *after* `Jobs`.

Answer (score -1):

You Could Try This One

```
CREATE TABLE `NAMES` (
  `FirstName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LastName` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Address` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Job` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Job` (`Job`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `Jobs` (
  `Job` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Salary` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Assistant` varchar(5) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `Job` (`Job`),
  CONSTRAINT `Jobs_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`Job`) REFERENCES `NAMES` (`Job`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Answer (score -1):

you can make any column a foreign key only when the column is a primary key or part of primary key of another table. Reference [click](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

Comment: There are subtle inaccuracies in your answer, and you are linking to a MySQL resource when the question is for Oracle.